# Bourne shell: Force STDOUT to STDERR

Tags: shell, sh

I am creating a Subversion [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit). I need to force the output of one command to STDERR, so that the post-commit hook will marshal the message back to the client.

How can I force STDOUT to STDERR?

In this simplified example, the file `foo` exists, but `bar` does not.

```
# touch foo
# ls foo bar
ls: bar: No such file or directory
foo
```

I want to send STDOUT to STDERR. I assumed that I could do this with `>&2`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I was expecting following example to redirect STDOUT to STDERR, and that `/tmp/test` would would contain the output and error for the command. But instead, it appears that STDOUT is never redirected to STDERR, and thus `/tmp/test` only contains the error from the command.

```
# ls foo bar >&2 2>/tmp/test
foo
# cat /tmp/test
ls: bar: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

I have tried the above example on CentOS, Ubuntu, FreeBSD and MacOSX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

shell redirects are evaluated one-at-a-time, left-to-right.  So when you have:

```
# ls foo bar >&2 2>/tmp/test
```

That FIRST redirects stdout to stderr (whatever it was initially -- probably the terminal) and THEN redirects stderr to /tmp/test.  So stdout will be left pointing at whatever stderr was originally pointed at and not at the file.  You want

```
# ls foo bar 2>/tmp/test >&2
```

redirect stderr to the file FIRST, and THEN redirect stdout to the same place.

Answer (score -2):

STDOUT has the number 1 file descriptor, which you also need to specify. So you're just missing a 1.

```
$ ls bar 1>&2 2>test
$ cat test
ls: cannot access bar: No such file or directory
```

From the man page for bash, under REDIRECTIONS:-

```
Appending Standard Output and Standard Error
   This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be appended to the
   file whose name is the expansion of word.

   The format for appending standard output and standard error is:

          &>>word

   This is semantically equivalent to

          >>word 2>&1
```

Comment: I believe that `1>&2` and `>&2` are equivalent. In any event, using `1>&2` produces the exact same result. For your command, try `ls foo bar`, after creating the file `foo`. What do you get?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. You can give both stdout and stderr the same name, concatenating the output that way. i.e. `ls bar >test 2>test`

Comment: Thanks, but how does that help me Force STDOUT to STDERR?

Comment: I think you might have to use a pipe for this, and echo the output.. That works at least:  ls foo 2>&1 | cat -